# How to run python script (which has some functions written in it) in sagemaker?

Tags: python, docker, machine-learning, knn, amazon-ecr

I have python `script.py`, which is a KNN machine learning algorithm writer from scratch.
Just using pandas and numpy libraries.
Script contains all the functions.
It takes some arguments such as `train_data`, `test_data`, `k_val` etc. And I want to run this in the **sagemaker**.
Looking for a solution how I can put this script in docker image and invoke it in **sagemaker** from **ECR container**.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called **SageMaker BYOC (Bring Your Own Container)**.

SageMaker has pre-built containers for most of the ML algorithms, however for custom algorithms and custom code it provides support for creating custom containers.

They are basically of 2 types:
If your goal is to train a model, run validation & save the model file.
`-Training Container`

If your goal is to use an existing model for inference, with SageMaker Endpoint Hosting or Batch Transform.
`-Serving Container`

Refer to this [repository](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/aws_marketplace/creating_marketplace_products/algorithms/container) for detailed steps.
The files `predictor.py` & `serve` are the most important, which contain your custom code.

References:
[Link1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/docker-containers.html)
[Link2](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality/tensorflow_bring_your_own)